# Laplace Operator notation

Tags: derivatives, sobolev-spaces

we defined the norm in a Sobolev space $W^{k,p}$ as $||u||_{W^{k,p}(\Omega)}:=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}||D^{\alpha}u||_{L^p{(\Omega)}}$ but we also said that with $W^{2,2}(\Omega)=H^2(\Omega)$ it is $||u||_{H^2}=||u||_{L^2}+||\nabla u||_{L^2}+||\Delta u||_{L^2}$.

Question: when do you use $D^1u$ and when $\nabla u$ (or $D^2u$, $\Delta u$)? Especially in the Poincare-inequality for example. It was mentioned that for smooth functions with compact support the identity $||D^2u||_{L^2}^2=||\Delta u||_{L^2}^2$ holds. Why? How to prove it?

Thanks!

Comment: For your last question, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4333453/629362)

Comment: @ArcticChar thank you but somehow I don't know how this helps me... what exactly is $D^2u$? I know $\Delta u =\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}u$

Comment: $D^2u$ is the Hessian matrix of $u$. Anyway, the LHS of the answer I linked is exactly the term $\|D^2 u\|^2_{L^2}$